# jQueryUI animate(color) doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I want to animate background color of input element, but it doesn't works :(

JavaScript (when submit):

```
function sendImage() {
    formularz = $('form#sendImage');
    autor = formularz.children('input[name=autor]');

    if (autor.val().length < 1 || autor.val().length > 20) {
        console.log('start');
        autor.animate({
            backgroundColor: 'red',
            width: '100px',
        }, 3000, function() {
            console.log('end');
        });
    }
}
```

jQuery liblaries:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.css">
<script src="jquery-ui/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<!-- I tried also this -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

In JS function works well - logs in console are shown, width of element too is changing, but background color not and it do not show any errors in console.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `background-color` instead of `backgroundColor` ?

Comment: @noob if using the property name as a literal then you cannot include the `-` as it's invalid, so you would need to use a string. jQuery is smart enough that it can accept either the CSS property or the DOM style property names. So in this case any of the following would work: `'background-color'`, `backgroundColor`, `'backgroundColor'`

Comment: @Invictus Note that you're including multiple versions of jQuery and jQueryUI - you should remove one of each.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery cannot animate background colours by default. You have two options, first you could use a third party plugin. Secondly, you can use CSS. The latter is preferable. Here's how to do it by setting the `transition` CSS rule on the element and then just adding the class in your jQuery code.

```
input {
    transition: all 3s;
}
input.error {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```js
function sendImage() {
    var $formularz = $('form#sendImage');
    var $autor = $formularz.children('input[name=autor]');

    if ($autor.val().length < 1 || $autor.val().length > 20) {
        $autor.addClass('error');
    }
}
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/8u3yzsdp/)

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure in Javascript you need to indicate you are adding style to an element via its id. So if you set an element's Id to be autor it would work using the following in your if statement:

```
document.getElementById('autor').style.background-color="red";
```

Comment: But this is without animation (guess).

Answer (score 0):

Rory McCrossan, I tested your recommendations and `'backgroundColor'` worked well, but later i wanted to check again the `backgoundColor` and it also works...

So I don't know what was wrong. Mayby some typo or I forgot about somethink.
Sorry for the confusion.